# Java Plugins - How to compile / export jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, jar

I've pulled all non-essential logic out of my runnable jar, and created plugins to facilitate this logic. I'm running into conceptual issues concerning the exportation into jars. Lets say I have the primary service and two plugins.

```
package/main.java    
package/plugins/foo.java    
package/plugins/bar.java
```

I would like to mirror this setup as exported jars. There should be `main.jar`, then `foo.jar` and `bar.jar` in the plugins folder. I currently have all three as different packages within the same java project. Should I be pulling the plugins out of the project into their individual projects to export manually? Should I look into some ANT compilation and leave this within one project?

I'm also a little bit in the dark as to how these will keep their references to one another. For example, foo and bar both extend main in some way. I'd like a little bit of insight into this process as well.

Eclipse IDE

Comment: it seems this's not really "plugins" as in my common knowledge, but actually just 3 processes in one project:  foo & bar both have main methods, and they both extend from main.java.  In eclipse, one project only exports to ONE jar file. If you want 3 jars, then 3 projects :) If 3 projects, then you'll need to put main.jar in the foo project & bar project for them to able to compile. Anyway, I don't see any value in doing that. You can always run main methods using just one jar file.

Comment: The purpose of making them plugin-like is because I need to be able shut down bar, alter it, and turn it back on without any user interaction. I've done a bit of reading about plugins, and rather than using a regular classloader, I've begun using a JARClassLoader which is doing an appropriate job at what I've described above. The trouble being I need to export each main class individually at current. It seems like any other plugin explanation I've seen described, where they all implement Plugin to use certain necessary methods. I'm just curious how they export, I suppose they don't use main?

Comment: I see. As being plugins, I think foo & bar need their own project. Their projects will have to import main.jar as dependency. However, when exporting foo & bar, you don't need to export as runnable jar. Instead, export them as normal jar and only keep the classes & resources needed for that plugin to work. Plugin development generally should be independent from main-app development. In case you want to keep those classes in one project, its' still possible to export multiple jars from one project: main.jar as runnable, and foo.jar as normal jar which stripped all the unneccessary part.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing it correct, you need foo.jar and bar.java in main.jar. If that's the case and foo and bar are independent of each other, you should keep them as separate plugins and list these plugins as dependencies of main.jar. I have not worked with ANT but I believe this is how the dependencies are managed like in Maven